# Sort Date via Linux "Sort" Command

Tags: linux, sorting, sed

I have sorted the 5th and 6th columns (latitude/longitude pairs) of the text below, and have attempted to sort the 2nd column by the code as follows:

```
sort -t, -k5 -V -k6 -V -rk2 -V file.txt
```

The dates below are close, but are still slightly out of order. How would I go about correctly sorting them in order?

```
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
```

Edit: I am trying to achieve the following result: 
Note the final result contains the 1979-01-01 and 1979-01-02 rows grouped together in chronological order in their respective latitude and longitude bounds:

```
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov - I have updated my post above.

Comment: So you are sorting by `5th` and `6th` (in increasing order) and you then want to further sort by the `2nd` (in increasing order)?

Comment: I think what you need is `sort -t, -k5,5gr -k6,6gr -k2,2` as described by @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: @Sundeep - that has done it. Thank you.

Comment: Additional thanks to @DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, it looks like you are overthinking `sort` a bit. You can use something similar to:

```
$ sort -t, -k6nr -k5 < file
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/a2.txt
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sort -t, -k6nr -k5 < dat/a2.txt
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,50,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49.5,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 00:00:00","1979-01-01 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 06:00:00","1979-01-01 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 12:00:00","1979-01-01 12:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-01 18:00:00","1979-01-01 18:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 00:00:00","1979-01-02 00:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
"1979-01-02 06:00:00","1979-01-02 06:00:00","XXX","YYY",-80,49,ZZZ
```

Let me know if I understood the sort order you are trying to achieve. If not, I'm happy to help further.

Comment: That is the correct order - I believe I was overthinking it a bit - thank you!

Comment: This is sorting on the whole line for the same lat/long pair, so it'll sort on field 1 first and THEN sort on field 2. You're only getting the expected output because field1 and field2 always have the same value in the sample input.